# Discouraged Configuration: Value other than autosizing specified for width (System items, other than fixed spaces, should use autosizing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

In XCode 6 building for iOS 8 I get the following warning:

```
MainStoryboard.storyboard: notice: Discouraged Configuration: Value other than autosizing specified for width (System items, other than fixed spaces, should use autosizing)
```

There seem to have been a question like this on StachOverflow before but it is removed. Cannot find any other information on Google.

Clicking on the warning leads me to a UIBarButtonItem with width 70 and 0 as Images Insets. Setting width to 0 does not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The question asked nearly 2 years ago, but I will give an answer anyways in case anyone is looking for an answer of such question.

In the Size Inspector of the `UIBarButtonItem` you mentioned, which you also probably set it as a **system defined** bar button item (e.g. **refresh**, **done**, **edit** etc.), you may have explicitly entered a **width value** there.

It expects you to **not** enter any **width value** other than caused by autosizing if you select a system type for a `UIBarButtonItem`.